# Is it possible to create an OSX style dock toolbar in windows using MFC or .NET?

Tags: .net, mfc, window

Full disclosure, I know the answer to this question is yes but I'm hoping there is a better way.

I maintain an application which uses the MFC CAppBar to create a "dock" that can be docked on any edge of the screen or as a floating window.  It was originally written in the 90s and has been updated only enough to keep it working throughout the years.  I'm looking for a solution to replace the entire app but my google searches are only returning results for docking windows within an MDI type application rather than docking/pinning the application itself.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to some potential classes/frameworks that can handle this sort of behavior (or at least something close enough that I can submit it as an alternative)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPF to create a specifically sized and placed Window with TopMost=true and WindowStyle=None. You should be able to implement your docking functionality by handling some combination of mousedown/mousemove events.

Comment: Bogus. Why would WPF add anything over just going with MFC, if your answer is: *"Well, you'll have to write code for this yourself"*? It's vague, proposes the wrong way to solve the issue, and completely misses to address the question. No idea, why this received an up-vote.

Comment: The OP expressed a desire to create an "OSX style" dock toolbar. Assuming that meant more than an OS/2 style button grid, it implied they wanted something that had better graphics support, could cleanly scale between varying resolutions, and utilize hardware acceleration to take advantage of the types of animations/transitions that are expected/inherent with an OSX style dock toolbar. 
I am not aware of any remotely easy way of creating the desired output using MFC (spent many years developing MFC applications).

Comment: Pretty impossible to guess, why you believe that WPF had better graphics support than some undisclosed subsystem. And frankly, nothing in Mac OS X' dock would even require hardware acceleration. But if you insist that hardware acceleration is mandatory, then going with WPF is the worst possible way to take advantage of it. Why recommend an API that forces all code to go through a managed interface, just to talk to a native implementation? Why not suggest to use the composition engine instead, that puts an end to this lunacy?